# modifying napili community template lightning components

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

Is there a way to view & modify the code of standard lightning components that are visible when editing the Napili template in the community builder.
I was wondering if I could modify some of the code and use it as lightning out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard components cannot be modified. However you can add custom components to your Napili community pages (you need update your template to the Winter ’16 version), and there are two approaches:

- You could create a subclass for some components marked extensible="true" such as ui:button, provided of course that the behavior that you want to modify can be achieved with such a construct.
- For the non-extensible components or for more customization, you can reimplement to your needs. If the component that you want to modify is open-sourced, you can look in the public repository for ideas:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui